# PHP: sprintf - zero without plus sign

Tags: php, regex, printf

I'm trying to get minus sign before negative numbers and plus sign before positive ones. I'm using sprintf.

```
sprintf("%+d",$voteCount)
```

This is working okay, except for zero. I don't want a plus sign before zero.
How can I get it to display plus sign for all positive numbers, but no sign for zero?

Comment: It is not duplicate!!!! Please reopen it. Go through the last para of the question.

Comment: Here is your alternative solution for your problem... *echo ($voteCount === 0 ? 0 : sprintf("%+d",$voteCount));*

Comment: use:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sign.php  by inabling `extension=php_gmp.so` in php.ini file

Comment: @RahulMeshram  you can add that into your answer in note section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve this, as %d will consider only positive and negative sign for whatever comes to it.

But yes, there is alternative way to achieve this as follows,

```
echo ($voteCount === 0 ? 0 : sprintf("%+d",$voteCount));
```

This should solve your problem.

**EDIT(As suggested by AliveToDie) :**

You can do the same by using [gmp_sign](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sign.php).

Here is reference example of it.

```
// positive
echo gmp_sign("500") . "\n";

// negative
echo gmp_sign("-500") . "\n";

// zero
echo gmp_sign("0") . "\n";
```

For the same, you need to enable extension in php.ini

```
extension=php_gmp.so
```